# Populate Google Sheet with Jamf Group data using its API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get a group of devices from Jamf MDM via its API and show in a Google sheet.
I think I'm almost there as this get the data but its not writing to the google sheet, I get an error of

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

What am I doing wrong to get the data into my Sheet?

```
function getGroup() {
  // Set the API URL and group ID
  const apiUrl = "https://MYURL/JSSResource/computergroups/id/377";


  // Make the request to the Jamf API
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic MYKEY",
      "Accept": "application/xml"
    }
  });
  
  // Parse the response as XML
  const xml = XmlService.parse(response.getContentText());
  const root = xml.getRootElement();
  var computers = root.getChildren("computer")
  var list=[]

    computers.forEach(function(item){
    var computer=[]
    item.getChildren().forEach(function(details){
      computer.push(details.getValue())
    })
    list.push(computer)
  })

  Logger.log(response.getContentText())
  
  // Create a new Google Sheet and set the first column to the list of computers
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()  
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list)
  

}
```

Comment: Hi, are you 100% sure you fetching data correctly? if you get that error, it is because there is no values in the array "list". I suggest you console.log within the forEach the values you you supposedly pushing to "list". Also in the Jamf API documentation should give back a  response code. you could maybe also get that value to understand if you are successfuly retreiving the data... try maybe this: const responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
Or something similar, sorry but I am not familiar with that APP (Jamf)

Comment: As mentioned by Matias, the error means that the `list` array is empty, which could mean that the `computers` array is empty, or that the `details` node was always empty, or maybe nothing was even returned by `response.getContentText()`. Either your parsing is wrong or there is no data. Try to log your variables from the response to computers to find out where you're getting empty values or some error.

Comment: What does this show you `Logger.log(response.getContentText())`

Comment: The log is showing a lot of info being pulled via the API

Comment: Still not able to get this to work. I'm seeing data in the log so cant work out why the error.

Comment: Did you check the remaining variables to figure out where it fails? `list` after pushing all the lines, `computers` after getting all the child nodes, the `details` variable? It's hard for us to figure out the cause without knowing the xml structure or having sample data, but to debug this you can start by first testing to find the breaking point.